# sed process multiple lines in one pass

Tags: shell, sed, syntax

I have two lines in the file like below:

```
#foo:
#   bar=<need replacement>
```

I'd like to remove the `#` if it exists(uncomment the line) for the two lines when the first line starting with `foo` and the second line contains `bar` and replace the text between `<>`.

Can I do this in one pass with `N;P;D` cycle using sed? Or is there any other simpler way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

Using a POSIX [sed](/questions/tagged/sed) with a standard `N;…;P;D;` loop and basic regexes
([BRE](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap09.html#tag_09_03)):

```shell
sed -e '$!N' -e '/^#\(foo:\n\)#\([[:blank:]]*bar\)=.*/ s//\1\2=newvalue/' -e P -e D < file
```

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -E '/^#?foo/{N;/\n.*bar/{s/^#//mg;s/(\n.*<).*(>.*)/\1replace\2/};P;D}' file
```

If the current line begins with `foo` commented or uncommented, then:

- Append the following line
- If the following line contains the word `bar`, then:

  - Delete any leading `#` in either of the two lines.
  - Replace any characters between `<` and `>` on the second line with `replace`.
- Print/delete the first of the two lines and repeat.

N.B. This allows a leading `foo` followed by another leading `foo` followed by `bar` to be processed.

Answer (score 0):

It can probably be done, but I would use a different tool. How about Awk?

```sh
awk -v replace="new value" 'm && /^[^:]+:/ { m=0 }
  /^#foo:/ { m=1 }
  m { sub(/^#/, ""); s(/<[^<>]*>/, replace) }1'
```

This follows the familiar pattern of setting a state variable `m` when we see the beginning of the interesting region, performing the replacements when we are in the region, and turning off the variable when we see the beginning of a new region (speculating somewhat on what the condition for that might look like).

It's not hard to alter this to simply look for a fixed number of lines after the start of the region; set the state variable to a number, and decrement it for each line.

If this is a Makefile, using a `make` variable would be a lot more elegant and robust, though.

```
ifdef ENABLE
foo:
    bar=$(barvalue)
endif
```

(or perhaps simply `ifdef barvalue`!)